# Creating an object in one thread and accessing it another with std::atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In C++11, if I create an object in one thread and set it to a `std::atomic<T*>`, is it guaranteed that the constructor will have finished executing before the atomic variable is set?

Specifically, in the following code, if the "if" statement evaluates true, is it guaranteed that the Widget() constructor has completed?

```
std::atomic<Widget*> widget = NULL;
```

In thread A:

```
widget = new Widget();
```

In thread B:

```
if(widget) {
    // Do something with widget
}
```

Comment: The assignment is post-construction.

Comment: I think you will find this useful: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: the effects of the constructor are sequenced-before the assignment to `widget` per 5.17 [expr.ass]/1 "In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.". The constructor completion therefore happens-before any read of `widget` that synchronizes-with the write of `widget` in question.

Comment: Hm... I may be wrong, but I'm thinking that section is talking about the sequencing of the pointer value, not the content of the actual object pointed to. I can't see any reason for an `atomic` to by default throw up a full memory barrier for a regular single value write operation.

Comment: The value computation of the right hand operand of that assignment evaluates the expression `new Widget()`. That evaluation involves allocation of memory for and value-initialization of a `Widget`. The assignment operator forces the effects of that evaluation to be sequenced before the assignment to the left-hand operand. This has nothing to do with the left-hand operand being atomic or not, and provides us the necessary guarantee in a single-threaded program that we can immediately start using the result of a `new` expression without somehow waiting for the construction to complete.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The fact that the left-hand operand is atomic enforces an ordering on the memory operations: any writes sequenced before the write to the atomic cannot be reordered after that atomic write without violating sequential consistency. (If a compiler must "throw up a full memory barrier" to guarantee that such reorderings don't happen, then so be it.)

Comment: +1 You're absolutely correct, I did not remember `std::memory_order_seq_cst` being the default memory order for `std::atomic`. It does actually throw up the full memory barrier I was expecting not to be there; `Total sequential ordering requires a full memory fence CPU instruction on all multi-core systems. This may become a performance bottleneck since it forces the affected memory accesses to propagate to every core.` and will work as you're describing.